# How do I handle the following situation in Python?

Tags: python, c

I want to say

```
a[current] = value
```

rather than saying

```
a.append(value)
```

because I want to show that the current value is value. The former listing shows this better. I come from C, so I am a bit confused with python lists. In C I preallocate space, so a[current] would exist and contain junk before I assign it value. Can I do something similar in Python?

Comment: The number 1 thing to realize is that python isn't C. Don't assume it acts like C, and try to translate its behavior into C code. They're very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first started using Python I ran into this problem all the time. You can do things like '[0]*10', but is inelegant, and will cause you problems if you try to do the same thing for lists of lists.

I finally solved the problem by realizing most of the time I just needed to reformulate the problem into something more pythonic. List comprehensions (as noted above) will almost always be the correct answer. If you are preallocating space, that means you are probably going to iterate over some other list, do some operation, then set an element in the new list to that value:

```
 newList = [op(e) for e in oldList]
```

You can get fancier. If for example, you don't want all the elements, you can set up a filter:

```
 newList = [op(e) for e in oldList if e < 5]
```

which will only put items that are less than 5 into the newList.

However, sometimes list comprehension isn't want you want. For example, if you're doing math-oriented coding, then numpy can come to the rescue:

```
  myVector = numpy.zeros(10)
```

will create an array with 10 elements.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like

```
[0] * 10
```

which will result in

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But your approach will probably not be very "pythonic". If switching to Python, you should also think about thinking in python. ;-)

Comment: +1 for advice to use the idioms of the language you're writing in.

Comment: Good advice. However, if you know that your array will grow till a fixed and high value, it is better, in a performance vintage point, to preallocate your array since, on graduals appends, Python will realloc on the underlying C array (of course, I'm talking about the CPython implementation (default in most platforms))

Comment: Are you sure about that? I don't think that python lists are implemented as C arrays.

Comment: About idioms, Yes, I realize that. I need to switch to numpy soon cause I do mostly numeric work, but in the meantime I am good enough with code style to realize that the listing sucks, but too bad with python to do anything about it :)

Comment: @jason: "too bad with python to do anything about".  False.  You asked -- which is huge.  You got an answer.  You can fix your code.

Comment: @Achim give a look at listobject.c in Python's source code. You'll have to look some other places, but this file is the first one you shall look to understand Python list's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate a list of length `n` by using

```
my_list = [None] * n
```

Obviously, the list will be initialised rather than containing junk.

That said, note that often a list comprehension is a good replacement for a loop containing calls to `list.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list with `n` elements initialized to zero (read "preallocate") in Python, use this:

```
somelist = [0] * n
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: hmm, this certainly clears things up a bit. Instead of allocating memory you initialize it to signal the compiler(interpreter) to set aside those bits. interesting.

Comment: jason: Not really. You don't have to allocate ANYTHING in Python. This is just to make sure you don't get any key errors (see a list as a C++ vector with `operator[]` set to `.at()`).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `append`, you can do things like

```
a = [None]*10
for i in range(10):
    a[i] = something()
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested also in python [arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most approximate syntax would be:

```
a.insert(current, value)
```

but if current isn't the last position in the array, insert will allocate some extra space and shift everything after current in one position. Don't know if this is the desired behavior. The following code is just like an append:

```
a.insert(len(a), value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining a separate `current` variable to indicate where the next item will be inserted (that is, your line `a[current] = value` is followed immediately by `current += 1` and you *wish* you could just write `a[current++] = value`), then you're writing C in Python and should probably stop.  :-)

Otherwise you probably want to preallocate the list with the number of items you want it to contain, as others have shown. If you want a list that will automatically *extend* to fill in missing values, such that `a[100] = value` will work even if the list only has 50 items, this can be done with a custom `__setitem__()` method on a list subclass:

```
class expandinglist(list):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        length = len(self)
        if index < length:
            list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
        elif index = length:     # you don't actually need this case, it's just a bit
            self.append(value)   # faster than the below for adding a single item
        else:
            self.extend(([0] * (index - length)) + [value])

lyst = expandinglist()
lyst[5] = 5
print lyst

>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that the current value is 'value', why don't you just use a variable for it?

```
a.append(value)
current_value = value
```